# Visual Studio shortcut to undo or roll back uncommitted changes to selected line

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Visual Studio is aware of uncommitted changes as evidenced through both team explorer and the optional margin highlighting of lines.

Is there a way or shortcut to revert or undo the uncommitted change for a *single selected line*?